# What online resources should I use to learn harmony and musical analysis?

Tags: theory, learning, harmony

I had some harmony courses and I want to learn some more about it.

Ideally, I am looking for is a [KhanAcademy](http://www.khanacademy.org/)-like website about [harmony](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmony) and [musical analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_analysis). If that doesn't exist, where else should I go ?

Comment: Here's a [related question](http://music.stackexchange.com/q/623/120). It seems IMSLP has many freely available treatises on harmony.

Answer (score 5):

Edward Sarath's [Music Theory Through Improvisation](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0415997259) is [available online](http://books.google.com/books?id=6vnjUO9HsxwC&pg=PP1), thanks to google books. The subtitle of the book ("A New Approach to Musicianship Training") seems to address your situation directly. You may also find my posts [about another book](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/4024/how-do-you-compose-using-the-chromatic-scale/4038#4038) and [about chord functions](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2290/what-exactly-should-i-have-to-learn-to-understand-why-certain-combination-of-cho/4211#4211) useful.

Answer (score 2):

hmmm, big topics...
Ya seen http://www.dolmetsch.com/theoryintro.htm ?

also http://www.musicarrangers.com/star-theory/p01.htm  ( menu on the right...:/ )
and  http://www.songtrellis.com/

Answer (score 1):

This site provides something Khan academy like: [Dave Conservatoire](http://www.daveconservatoire.org/).

Also, try searching for harmony treatises on [IMSLP](http://imslp.org/). They've got some good stuff like a short treatise on harmony by Peter Tchaikovsky.

Answer (score 0):

[Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/) has some [courses about music](https://www.coursera.org/category/music) including this one: [How music works](https://www.coursera.org/course/howmusicworks). You have to enroll and you can only follow the course when it starts. No date is announced yet.

> #### About the Course
>
> Designed as a course for all students, regardless of background, “How
>   Music Works” is appropriate for anyone with a love of music and a
>   curiosity about how it functions.  Prior experience with music is
>   welcome but not required, and music reading ability is not needed in
>   order to participate.  Topics covered include: rudiments of musical
>   notation and analysis, psychoacoustics, meaning in music, and the
>   interaction of the basic building blocks of sonic art such as rhythm,
>   melody, and harmony.  Activities include examinations of musical
>   examples from a variety of cultures and time periods, in-class music
>   making, and readings that address the techniques of musical creation
>   and the power and importance that music has in all human societies.